# foreign key only show owner field django

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have two Model classes In django restful API:

```
class Titles(models.Model):
    title_links=models.CharField(max_length=500)
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.title_links)

class All(models.Model):
    created_by=models.ForeignKey(User,null=True)
    title1=models.ForeignKey(Titles,related_name='title1',blank=True,null=True,limit_choices_to={'created_by': True},)
```

In All class In title1 field I want only those titles who is created_by current logged in user.

Comment: A ForeignKey field can only point to one instance to begin with. You'd need a [ManyToManyField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/).

Comment: I want only those titles from Titles model in the title1 field of All ,  who is created_by current logged in user

Comment: You mean as choices in the admin or in a form?

Comment: Yes . I am using Rest API . Same  as choices in the admin or in a form

Comment: Just use `Titles.objects.filter(created_by=user)`.

Comment: In which section , in models.py , serializers.py or in views.py ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally i got the ans .

In serializers.py

```
class AllSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(AllSerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    user = self.context['request'].user
    self.fields['title1'].queryset = All.objects.filter(created_by=user)

class Meta:
    model=All
    fields='__all__'
```

Thats it . Thanks